# How to set mark in yaml-mode using ergoemacs-mode keybinding?

Tags: emacs, yaml, ergoemacs

I am Emacs (v24.5) newbie and I use it with *[ergoemacs-mode](https://ergoemacs.github.io/)* (v5.14.7.3.1) key-bindings.

I often need to edit data in YAML format manually and I do it in *[yaml-mode](https://github.com/yoshiki/yaml-mode)* (v20160101.921) because of its highlighting and proper indenting.

However, when I try to *set-mark* in *yaml-mode* with *ergoemacs-mode* keys `M-SPC` it does nothing and only says:

> edmacro-parse-keys: M- must prefix a single character, not SPc

Could you, please, suggest how can I make `M-SPC` behave in *yaml-mode* as it does everywhere else in Emacs (i.e., *org-mode*, *ess*).

**Edit:** Solved in newer version of ergoemacs-mode

Comment: It's possible that you (or `ergoemacs-mode`) have bound `M-SPC` to `set-mark`, but normally this is bound to `C-SPC`. In any case, what is `M-SPC` actually bound to (check with `C-h k M-SPC`)?

Comment: Chris, thank you for your question. I did not modify any keys myself yet so by default `ergoemacs-mode` bounds `M-SPC` (in my case it is actually `⌘SPC`) to `set-mark-command` (I checked that with `C-h k M-SPC`).

Comment: probably a bug. If you file it on github, am pretty sure matt'd fix it right away.

Comment: Thanks to Matt! The issue was fixed in a newer version of ergo-emacs.